# DictVectorizer Recognize Feature as String

Tags: python, dictionary, numpy, scikit-learn

The list of dictionaries that I am running through DictVectorizer (0.14) have specific categorical values that have been encoded to integers:

```
> dictionary_list[0:2]
```

Out:

```
[{u'Life': 3377, u'SerumX': 1015, u'duration': 3, u'gene_name': 37},
 {u'Life': 11655, u'SerumX': 1913, u'duration': 3, u'gene_name': 1}]
```

> vec = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
>   X = vec.fit_transform(dictionary_list)

For example genes APC, AXIN1, BLM might be encoded as 37, 1, 15 via some arbitrary method. That is to say these numbers are not some NLP expression of the characters/ngrams etc.

I am currently updating dicts within this list to convert values for key 'gene_name' from int to str :

```
for dicts in dictionary_list:
   dicts.update((k, str(v)) for k, v in dicts.iteritems() if k == 'gene_name')

> dictionary_list[0:2]
```

Out:

```
[{u'Life': 3377, u'SerumX': 1015, u'duration': 3, u'gene_name': '37'},
 {u'Life': 11655, u'SerumX': 1913, u'duration': 3, u'gene_name': '1'}]
```

I'm looking to optimize speed and avoid having to update the dict before passing it through DictVectorizer.  I'm curious if there is a way to pass my list to DictVectorizer in a manner in which I can have it coerce the value of 'gene_name' as a string to utilize the built in encoding.

Many thanks to the scikit-learn team for their excellent work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What does the data initially look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can speed things a bit if you change your code to something like

```
for dct in dictionary_list:
    if 'gene_name' in dct:
        dct['gene_name'] = str(dct['gene_name'])
```

I think you can't get away from coercing values to strings, as DictVectorizer uses `isinstance(value, six.string_types)` as a condition to filter out categorical values in provided data.

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience gents. I'll look into making a contribution to sklearn to add functionality regarding coercing specific column arrays as strings.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code right, you are looping through all the keys to see if one of them is `"gene_name"` I'm guessing you are doing this because not all dictionaries might have that key.

If you did:

```
for dic in records_list:
    if 'gene_name' in dic:
        dic.update({ 'gene_name' , str(dic['gene_name']) })
```

you only access the key you want to change.

Comment: Hey Magellan, I believe what you've provided is the same as my list comprehension I shared above. I just edited my question to help clarify though. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @KLDavenport while equivalent, the code in this answer should be more effective than yours for the reasons stated in answer.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but I'm having a hard time seeing the difference, I'm also doing a for and if statement right?

Comment: @KLDavenport your if is inside a generator comprehensis, so it checks all the dict items, that is O(n) (n is dict length), and `if key in dct` is a dict lookup with O(1) complexity.

Comment: I understand now thank you. I notice your answer doesn't contain and update like Magellan's, your code would create a new dict then?

Comment: I have to hand it to alko, his code is clearer most probably more efficient. If you are sure that every dictionary contains the "gene_name" keyword, you can also leave out the if statement. You might also consider a try:... except KeyError: clause instead